# Null springSecurityService causes encodePassword to fail in Grails 2.0.1

Tags: grails, spring-security

We are working on a new project with Grails 2.0.1 and Spring Security. The create user context fails due to springSecurityService in the User domain object being null. Strangely this occurs only our Linux text box while on all the developer windows boxes it works fine. Not sure if it has anything to do with the environment or whether it is something else. On the linux box this fails consistently.

The user domain class we are using is below (the plugin generated class with a couple of additional fields).  The encodePassword is being handled by the beforeInsert(), beforeUpdate() triggers.

Came across this thread which talks about the transient references causing problems in webflows, which I assume are not being used here, so not sure if this is relevant.
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spring-Security-Plugin-1-of-the-time-springSecurityService-null-td4349941.html

```
class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    static constraints = {
        firstName blank: false, nullable: false, size: 2..100
        lastName blank: false, nullable: false, size: 2..100
        username blank: false, nullable: false, unique : true, email: true
        password blank: false, nullable: false, size: 6..255
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    /* user details */
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would prefer not using encodePassword in User domain, but in place when user is being created: controller, service, tests:
new User(username: "root", password: springSecurityService.encodePassword('1'))
I don't think that this is workaround or hack.

Comment: Then there's some way to create a new User instance without having its password encoded, since a caller does _not necessarily_ have to use encodePassword. This design decision ensures that the password is always encoded when the User domain is manipulated, which from a security standpoint is more robust.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use Groovy's meta-programming to override the encodePassword method if you only want to make sure the User object is saved and you don't care about the password for your test.

```
@TestFor(UserService)    
@Mock(User)
class UserServiceTest {
    void testMethod() {
        User.metaClass.encodePassword = { -> }

        service.invokeTestThatSavesUserDomainClass()
    }   
}
```

Comment: Snap that was simple. Exactly what I was looking for being new to testing and all. I read the other solutions on this and other SO posts about this same issue, this is by far the simplest solution!

Answer (score 3):

`springSecurityService` must NOT be transient. The following code should work

```
class User {

  def springSecurityService

  static transients = ["springSecurityService"]

  protected void encodePassword() {
      password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there are some problems with testing SpringSecurity service that is injected into User domain class. Take a look at this question: [How to test unit test controllers that use SpringSecurity service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516837/how-to-unit-test-controllers-that-use-springsecurityservice/8517042#8517042).

Answer (score 0):

Add these in User domain class:

```
static mapping = {
   autowire true
}
```

:)