# Is there any bug using both Spock and Spring Security plugin in same project?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, spock

I use both Spring and Spock plugins in my current project. I wrote a bunch of test cases in Spock. All are passing without any error (All are GREEN!). But the same tests are failing if I try to test the app after some time. I don't why this happens. This is the code (one of my failing test):

```
def 'list action: 1 user'() { 

   setup: 
      mockDomain(User,[userInstance]) 

   expect: 
      controller.list() == [userInstanceList: [userInstance] , userInstanceTotal: 1] 
      params.max == 10 

   where: 
      userInstance = new User(username:"antoaravinth",password:"secrets") 
}
```

I get a big error for this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method encodePassword() on null object 
        at mnm.schedule.User.encodePassword(User.groovy:34) 
        at mnm.schedule.User.beforeInsert(User.groovy:42) 
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.events.DomainEventListener.invokeEvent(DomainEventListener.java:188) 
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.events.DomainEventListener.beforeInsert(DomainEventListener.java:110) 
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.events.DomainEventListener.onPersistenceEvent(DomainEventListener.java:73) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:46) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.EntityPersister.cancelInsert(EntityPersister.java:227) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.NativeEntryEntityPersister.executeInsert(NativeEntryEntityPersister.java:1321) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.NativeEntryEntityPersister$1.run(NativeEntryEntityPersister.java:698) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.impl.PendingOperationExecution.executePendingOperation(PendingOperationExecution.java:33) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractSession.flushPendingOperations(AbstractSession.java:322) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractSession.flushPendingInserts(AbstractSession.java:314) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractSession.flush(AbstractSession.java:237) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.flushBeforeQuery(Query.java:596) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.list(Query.java:562) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.singleResult(Query.java:606) 
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.count_closure11(GormStaticApi.groovy:311) 
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:301) 
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:34) 
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.count(GormStaticApi.groovy:307) 
        at mnm.schedule.UserController.list(UserController.groovy:241) 
        at mnm.schedule.UserControllerSpec.list action: 1 user(UserControllerSpec.groovy:34)
```

The Domain class :

```
package mnm.schedule
import org.example.*;
class User extends SecUser {
    Profile profile
    String username
    String password
    static constraints = {
    username(unique:true,size:3..15, blank:false)
    password(blank:false)
    String toString() {
        this.username
    }

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }
    protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}

Set<SecRole> getAuthorities() {
    SecUserSecRole.findAllBySecUser(this).collect { it.secRole } as Set
}

def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}

}
```

The same test is passing at times and at time throwing this error. Whats wrong here? How can it pass at times and fail at times?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why its happening. But can you please copy the code of User.groovy? Looks like springSecurityService is null..Are you mocking that service?

Comment: @Saurabh : No I'm not mocking that service! How do I mock that?

Comment: @Saurabh: I do updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this blog as an example of mocking springSecurityService in domain objects

http://www.block-consult.com/blog/2011/08/17/inject-spring-security-service-into-domain-class-for-controller-unit-testing/ or check https://stackoverflow.com/a/9789619/206351